# HTML/Javascript как интерфейс к локальной базе данных SQLite

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

Я хочу написать простое приложение для баз данных SQLite, HTML/Javascript в качестве фронтенда. Никакого взаимодействия между клиентом и сервером быть не должно - я просто хочу, чтобы пользователи могли взаимодействовать с базой данных с помощью браузера, а не родной программы. Выбирали нужный им период и формировался отчет. Вопрос в том, как правильно реализовать это, либо, лучше идти каким-то другим путем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам по себе браузер имеет имплементацию javascript, но она не может быть расширена дополнительными модулями с бинарными библиотеками, такими как модуль для работы с sqlite. А если делать на чем-то вроде node.js тогда появляется клиент-серверная модель которую вы хотите избежать.

*Единственный вариант*, который я вижу для написания приложения в браузере и без клиент-серверной архитектуры: написать плагин к нужному браузеру, который в себе уже может содержать дополнительные библиотеки для работы с базой данных. И при этом не нужно писать ничего клиент-серверного.

*Но* предложенный вариант, на мой взгляд сложней и в написании и в обслуживании и в эксплуатации. Самый простой вариант, если вы знаете javascript то писать все-таки клиент-серверное приложение на чём-то вроде node.js (с готовым фреймворком express.js это будет достаточно быстро).